# How to use server data in MaterialViewPager?

Tags: android, api, server, retrofit

I use this library. **com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.1.3@aar**
How to use data that come from server in MaterialViewPager? Here, Kitchen", "Pork", "Fish", "Soup" are static, I want to change data that come from server; api.

```
mViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

        String[] categories = new String[]{"Kitchen", "Pork", "Fish", "Soup"}; // static, wanna come from server

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position % 4) {

                default:
                    return RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return categories.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return categories[position];
        }
    });
```

Here, retrofit; data come from server;

```
NetworkEngine.getInstance().getFoodCategory(new Callback<FoodCategory>() {

        @Override
        public void success(FoodCategory foodCategory, Response response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    });
```

here, api

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sea Foods",
    "description": "-",
    "icon": "photo_20160503084933_277342661make_money.png",
    "background": "photo_20160503084933_754915524make_money.png",
    "color": "#000FFF",
    "created_at": "2016-05-03 08:48:01",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-03 08:49:33",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
]
```

FoodCategory.java

```
public class FoodCategory implements Serializable{

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    @Expose
    private String icon;
    @SerializedName("background")
    @Expose
    private String background;
    @SerializedName("color")
    @Expose
    private String color;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("deleted_at")
    @Expose
    private Object deletedAt;

    /**
     * @return The id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id The id
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return The description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description The description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return The icon
     */
    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    /**
     * @param icon The icon
     */
    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    /**
     * @return The background
     */
    public String getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    /**
     * @param background The background
     */
    public void setBackground(String background) {
        this.background = background;
    }

    /**
     * @return The color
     */
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    /**
     * @param color The color
     */
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**
     * @return The createdAt
     */
    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param createdAt The created_at
     */
    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return The updatedAt
     */
    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param updatedAt The updated_at
     */
    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return The deletedAt
     */
    public Object getDeletedAt() {
        return deletedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param deletedAt The deleted_at
     */
    public void setDeletedAt(Object deletedAt) {
        this.deletedAt = deletedAt;
    }

}
```

Comment: Share the `FoodCategory` model class .

Answer (score 2):

You have some data parsing issue . You have to use `ArrayList<FoodCategory>` to get all list of data.

like this way .

```
NetworkEngine.getInstance().getFoodCategory(new Callback<ArrayList<FoodCategory>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(ArrayList<FoodCategory> foodCategory, Response response) {
             FragmentStatePager  adapter = new FragmentStatePager(YourActivity.this,foodCategory);
             mViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    });
```

So, pass the `ArrayList<FoodCategory>` to the `PagerAdapter`and use it's data to make the fragment.

Make a different `PagerAdapter` . Like this way .

```
public class FragmentStatePager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<FoodCategory> foodCategoryArrayList;
    ArrayList<String> categorieName = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public FragmentStatePager(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<FoodCategory> foodCategoryArrayList) {
        super(fm);
        this.foodCategoryArrayList = foodCategoryArrayList;
        for (FoodCategory foodCategory : foodCategoryArrayList) {
            categorieName.add(foodCategory.getName());
            YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putSerializable("FoodCategoryInfo", foodCategory);
            fragment.setArguments(data);
            fragmentArrayList.add(fragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentArrayList.size();
    }

    // If you want to show the title in the tab layout.
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return categorieName.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: ops , i forgot to initialize the Adapter . Check now .

Comment: `categories.add(foodCategory.getName());` should be `categorieName.add(foodCategory.getName());` :p . 

And `YourFragment` is the name of your fragment for the viewpager . Replace the name YourFragment by your fragment's name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110969/discussion-between-zahidul-islam-and-peter-phyo).

Answer (score 0):

I do this in following way

first of all create a abstract **BaseFragment** class
like following :

```
public abstract class BaseListFragment extends Fragment implements SearchableFragment {

    private BaseListAdapter mAdapter;

    public abstract String getType();

    public abstract String getCategorySlug();

    public abstract String getCategoryId();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base_list, container, false);

        initViews(rootView);
        //call performSearch()

        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void performSearch() {

        // your request
        ServiceHelper.getInstance().searchQuery(getCategoryId(), getCategorySlug(), null, null, getType(), null, mPageRequest).enqueue(new Callback<List<ShortVideoModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ShortVideoModel>> call, Response<List<ShortVideoModel>> response) {
                processResponse(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ShortVideoModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                processResponse(null);
            }
        });

    }



}
```

Then create Your fragment class and inherite from **BaseFragment** and implement abstract methods (you can pass different type for different kinds of request call)

```
public class LatestVideoFragment extends BaseListFragment {

    private static final String TYPE_VIDEO_LATEST = "latest";

    public static LatestVideoFragment newInstance() {
        return new LatestVideoFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void performSearch() {
        super.performSearch();
    }

    @Override
    public String getCategorySlug() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCategoryId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return TYPE_VIDEO_LATEST;
    }

}
```

As you see you can customize **LatestVideoFragment** as you want.